# Getting the speed of a fluid streamline

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have the following streamline function,

$$(r^2 - \frac{a^3}{r})sin^2\theta = b$$

how do I get the speed of this fluid at each point on the streamfunction?

Incompressible, this is the streamline for very large r.

It is derived from the streamfunction in spherical polars for a fluid perturbed by a sphere,

$$\Psi(r,\theta) = -\frac{1}{2}U(r^2 - \frac{a^3}{r})sin^2\theta$$

Comment: You better specify your boundary condition and what sort of fluid this is (e.g. incompressible, irotational ). Otherwise, you will never have a unique solution.

Comment: have edited to specify

Comment: I apologise for misreading the question, now I look closer I am a little confused. The first expression you give is not a general definition for a streamline of the streamfunction below. A streamline is an equation describing a curve on which $\psi =$ constant. What information are you given and what have you derived?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The velocity of a fluid in terms of the streamfunction is $u = \nabla\wedge(0,0,\psi)$. The speed is then the magnitude of this vector. In terms of spherical polar co-ordinates:

$$u =\bigg(\frac1r\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial\theta},-\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial r},0\bigg)$$

Note that in general, the streamfunction contains a lot more information than the streamline equation. The streamline equation will give the curves in the plane that the streamlines flow across, but will not have information about the speed of the flow on an particular streamline.

Comment: Yes I agree, but I want to find the velocity of the fluid on this streamline, the $u = \nabla \psi$ wont give the velocity on the unique streamline path.

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't the $\psi$ in $u = \nabla \psi$ is usually called the velocity potential while the stream function is the name of those $\phi$ where $(u_x, u_y) = (\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}, -\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x})$?

Comment: $\Psi$ is the stream function with $u=\nabla \times \Psi$.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_function

Comment: @achillehui Indeed I was assuming that $\psi$ was the velocity potential, rather than the streamfunction. I saw something that looked familiar and didn't read the question fully, I apologise! I also realise now that what you give in the original question is not a streamline for the given streamfunction, although if you replace the $C$ with an $-a^3$ then it should be.

Comment: @tomoldfield, no problem. I know the math but not the exact naming conventions of these stuff. I just want to make sure.

Comment: @user57142 a streamline is a contour of $\psi$. That is, a curve along which $\psi$ is constant. The equation here is given by $\psi = \Psi(r,\theta) = -\frac{1}{2}U(r^2 - \frac{a^3}{r})\sin^2\theta =$ some constant. Where have you found this question? It might help if you posted it in it's entirety.